# PHP MySQLi doesn't recognize login info

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I can't login to the database using mysqli class.

I get the next error:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have the next code:

```
$this->mysqlCon = new mysqli($siteConfig['db']['hostname'], $siteConfig['db']['username'], $siteConfig['db']['password'], $siteConfig['db']['database']);
```

`var_dump()` of `$siteConfig['db']` returns:

```
array(4) {
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["username"]=>
  string(4) "root"
  ["password"]=>
  string(*) "***Censored***"
  ["database"]=>
  string(*) "***Censored***"
}
```

My VPS is running **Debian 6 32bit**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Warning: mysql_query()
             ^---------------------- notice something? :)
```

You seem to be mixing up `mysql` and `mysqli` in your code.

Comment: My hero! :D I mixed a script my friend provided, for learning, and seems like my eye can't differ between mysqli and mysql. Thanks :)